# Tomcat7 comes without the logs directory? Where to see Tomcat7 logs?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I recently installed Tomcat7 and it doesn't seem to come with a logs directory.  Does anyone know where to see the logs for Tomcat7?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normally under your ${catalina.base} directory location.  Check your ${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties file to see the location tomcat "thinks" it is writing to.